# How to join tables not by table_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I need (was ordered) to JOIN two tables by the CODE column (string). But the default (and the proper) way to join tables `Product.joins(:skus)` is to do so through `ID=TABLE_ID`
What is the best to go about this situation and is there a way to do so without having to write:

```
Product.joins("INNER JOIN skus ON skus.CODE = products.CODE")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on `ActiveRecord`'s documentation, you can specify the `primary_key` and `foreign_key` of a relationship.

`product.rb:`

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :skus, foreign_key: :code, primary_key: :code
end
```

`sku.rb:`

```
class Sku < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, foreign_key: :code, primary_key: :code
end
```

and now you can simply use `Product.joins(:skus)` or `Product.includes(:skus)` or event `Product.first.skus`